# Drawing equipments in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-styles

Is it possible to draw something like the following with tikz? If so, how should I start it? It looked way too advanced for me to have an idea of where to start off. Please let me know.

[image]

Comment: I suggest Ipe software for this. For instance, [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Erg4fp2H3Ds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Erg4fp2H3Ds)

Comment: Is it possible? Absolutely - see http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/ what can be done with Tikz. As to where to start: Have a look at http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/ and http://packages.oth-regensburg.de/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf. Start small and play with it. Don't try to start with your example. That's way too advanced for a beginner

Comment: You can use the `3d view` key of the `perspective` library or `tikz-3dplot`. This allows you to draw the block and the cylinders relatively easily. But with a graph of that complexity you will still need substantial efforts to succeed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a start, not an attempt to fully reproduce the diagram. You can establish some 3d view and then place the objects one by one. For repeating objects such as cylinders or cuboids it makes sense to define `pic`s. In order to project something on a coordinate plane, you can use the `3d` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective,3d}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{pics/3d cylinder z/.style={code={%
            \tikzset{3d/cylinder/.cd,#1}%
            \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d/cylinder/##1}}%
            \edef\mylocalaz{\pgf@view@az}%
            \draw[pic actions] %[left color=gray!90,right color=gray!60,middle color=gray!20] 
            plot[domain=\pgf@view@az:\pgf@view@az-180,variable=\t,smooth]
            ({\pv{r}*cos(\t)},
            {\pv{r}*sin(\t)},0)
            -- 
            plot[domain=\mylocalaz-180:\mylocalaz,variable=\t,smooth]
            ({\pv{r}*cos(\t)},
            {\pv{r}*sin(\t)},
            \pv{h}) 
            -- cycle;
            \draw[pic actions] %[fill=gray!30] 
            plot[domain=0:360,variable=\t,smooth cycle]
            ({\pv{r}*cos(\t)},
            {\pv{r}*sin(\t)},
            \pv{h}); 
            \pgfkeys{/tikz/3d/cylinder/extra}
    }},pics/cuboid/.style={code={%
        \tikzset{3d/cuboid/.cd,#1}%
        \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d/cuboid/##1}}%
  \draw[pic actions] 
  (-\pv{x}/2,-\pv{y}/2,-\pv{z}/2) 
  -- (-\pv{x}/2,-\pv{y}/2,\pv{z}/2) 
   -- (\pv{x}/2,-\pv{y}/2,\pv{z}/2) 
    -- (\pv{x}/2,-\pv{y}/2,-\pv{z}/2) -- cycle;
  \draw[pic actions] 
  (-\pv{x}/2,-\pv{y}/2,-\pv{z}/2) 
  -- (-\pv{x}/2,-\pv{y}/2,\pv{z}/2) 
   -- (-\pv{x}/2,\pv{y}/2,\pv{z}/2) 
    -- (-\pv{x}/2,\pv{y}/2,-\pv{z}/2) -- cycle;
  \draw[pic actions] 
  (-\pv{x}/2,-\pv{y}/2,\pv{z}/2) 
  -- (\pv{x}/2,-\pv{y}/2,\pv{z}/2) 
   -- (\pv{x}/2,\pv{y}/2,\pv{z}/2) 
    -- (-\pv{x}/2,\pv{y}/2,\pv{z}/2) -- cycle;
  }},
    3d/.cd,cylinder/.cd,r/.initial=1,h/.initial=2,extra/.code={},
    /tikz/3d/.cd,cuboid/.cd,x/.initial=1,y/.initial=1,z/.initial=1}
\makeatother    
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d view={-35}{25},line cap=round,line join=round]
 \path (0,0,0) pic{cuboid={x=4,y=5,z=3}} 
 (0,0,1.6)pic[fill=white]{cuboid={x=4.2,y=5.2,z=0.2}};
 \begin{scope}[canvas is yx plane at z=1.7]
  \draw[yshift=6mm,xscale=-1] foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(Mod(\X,60))}] 
  in {0,10,...,120} {(234-2.4*\X:0.5) -- (234-2.4*\X:0.8)
  \ifnum\Y=0
  node[pos=1.5,transform shape,font=\sffamily] {\X}
  \fi};
 \end{scope}
 \path(-1.3,1.8,1.7) pic[fill=white]{3d cylinder z={r=0.5,h=2}}
  (1.3,1.8,1.9) pic[fill=white]{cuboid={z=0.4}}
  (-1.3,-1.8,1.7) pic[fill=white]{3d cylinder z={r=0.3,h=0.2}}
  (-1.3,-1.8,1.9) pic[fill=white]{3d cylinder z={r=0.4,h=0.4,
  extra/.code={
  \draw foreach \t in {0,10,...,180}
  {({\pv{r}*cos(\mylocalaz-\t)},{\pv{r}*sin(\mylocalaz-\t)},0) 
  -- ({\pv{r}*cos(\mylocalaz-\t)},{\pv{r}*sin(\mylocalaz-\t)},\pv{h}) };
  }}};
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]